# Lua returns wrong values

Tags: c#, lua, nlua

I've got the following scenario:

1. I registered a c# function in nlua
2. This function is called like this in the lua script: `SomeFunction({Amount = 1})`
3. The c# function gets called but now the Amount is some arbitrary huge double

The code in which I register the function:

```
Lua LuaInterface = new Lua();
someFunction = (LuaTable t) => DoSomething(t);
LuaInterface.RegisterFunction("SomeFunction", someFunction.Target, someFunction.Method);
```

If I use the debugger, t is for example `{{ Amount = -2,05689484611373E-178 }}`

I've spent about two hours finding a bug in my code (the real one is far more complex) and this is just what I reduced the problem to.

Comment: Can you show how `DoSomething` is accessing `t.Amount` from C#?

Comment: By t["Amount"]. This returns a object. When I parse this object to a int I get a OverflowException

Comment: You don't need to use RegisterFunction to use delegates you can simply set a global variable using LuaInterface ["SomeFunction"] = someFunction;
And call from Lua using "SomeFunction(t)".
https://github.com/NLua/NLua/blob/master/tests/LuaTests.cs#L2374

Comment: @ Vinicius Jarina As far as I'm concerned SomeFunction({Amount = 1}) is valid Lua syntax. All scripts I have are written this way so it would be a huge effort to change all of them. Your way of registering the functions got rid of the exception but only by never calling the delegate. I guess I did something wrong there. `LuaInterface["SomeFunction"] = new Action<LuaTable>((LuaTable t) => DoSomething(t));`

Comment: Hi @I.k 1234 I am not sure what is wrong with your code. But this is working fine here http://screencast.com/t/qxmR2p9MBx
https://gist.github.com/viniciusjarina/18106975e78ac811a73b

Comment: @Vinicius Jarina Yeah it's kinda strange. I'll try to reproduce the bug on a different computer. Maybe its just some really uncommon external factor.

Comment: @I.k 1234  Try to update your Mono or you Xamarin.iOS/Xamarin.Android to the latest version.